# dynamically adding PXTabItem from codebehind

Tags: acumatica

Trying to add a new tab items from the page cs file in the Page_Init method which contains a PXSmartPanel in Iframe mode.

Initially I just created the blank tab

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    PXTabItem tabItem = new PXTabItem();
    tabItem.Key = "myKey"
    tabItem.Text = "myTab" + i;
    tabItem.Visible = true;
    this.tab.Items.Add(tabItem);

    PXSmartPanel smartPanel = new PXSmartPanel();
    smartPanel.RenderIFrame = true;
    smartPanel.InnerPageUrl = "thispage" + i;
    ..... {other smartpanel properties}
    tabitem.TemplateContainer.Controls.Add(smartPanel);
}
```

This does create the tabs on my page and works/looks correctly in Chrome however in Firefox, the style of the iframe rendered is always 150px regardless of the style set in the smartPanel above.

Tried adding the following

```
smartPanel.height = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage);
smartPanel.Style["height"] = "100%";
```

Tried even forcing a specific size of say 600px.

As a secondary test, I added directly to my page the tab items, smart panels and those render correctly in both Chrome and Firefox.

I also attempted to create a "dummy" / "template" and use the tabitem.CopyFrom() method to set it up.   This also renders correctly in chrome but not firefox.

Has anyone added tab items directly from the code behind file and have any hints on what property I am missing here?

Comment: Can you try setting <AutoSize Enabled="True" /> in the child Container Control of the TabItem, usually the child container is a Form or a grid.

Comment: Unfortunately no.   AutoSize in general with an iframe of an external source seems to cause problems.    I did try this as well but when AutoSize is enabled,  the iframe renders at 0px no matter what browser or method.